# How good is HP fortify tool for scanning public REST webservices?

Tags: fortify, rest-security

I need to analyze Fortify tool for scanning REST based webservices being developed for our product.
Does it provide support for the same or I might need to look at other tools.

Answer (score -1):

There is HP (Microfocus) webinspect for that. Fortify is for static cose analysis.

You can link both fortify and webinspect to fortify ssc if installed